# Difficulty in solving an non-homogeneous differential equation in 2D

Tags: differential-equations

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = 1;
b = 1;
c=D[w[x, y], {x, 4}] + 2*D[D[w[x, y], {x, 2}], {y, 2}] + D[w[x, y], {y, 4}]
eq = c - b^4 w[x, y] == f[x, y]
bc1 = w[0, y] == 0;
bc2 = w[a, y] == 0;
bc3 = w[x, 0] == 0;
bc4 = w[x, b] == 0;
bc5 = ((D[w[x, y], {x, 2}]) /. x -> 0) == 0
bc6 = ((D[w[x, y], {x, 2}]) /. x -> a) == 0
bc7 = ((D[w[x, y], {x, 2}]) /. y -> 0) == 0
bc8 = ((D[w[x, y], {x, 2}]) /. y -> b) == 0
f[x_, y_] := DiracDelta[x - z] DiracDelta[y - e]
gf[z_, x_, y_] := 
 GreenFunction[{eq[[1]], bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, bc5, bc6, bc7, bc7}, 
  w[x, y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, z]
```

I have a non-homogenous differential equation which is the 2D. I am trying to extract the analytical solution. An analytical solution exists and is reported in the journal paper, I am trying to reproduce results reported in the paper using Mathematica. Below is the link to that journal paper, I am trying to solve equation 10 in that paper. And the solutions for simply supported boundary conditions are given in section 4.1.
[Link to journal paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022460X83711193/1-s2.0-S0022460X83711193-main.pdf?_tid=4d631ab5-01c3-44a1-bb4a-1d4a7308e318&acdnat=1543302459_31e493b07a8249c5f37b0202ae6af418)

Comment: It is hardly useful to give a link to the journal, where I was asked to pay for the article.

Comment: I have a soft copy, is there any ways to upload the paper here?

Comment: You can use some site that can be open by third parties, like DropBox. Further, this: `(D[W[x, y], {x, 2}]) /. x -> 0 == 0` is incorrect. Mma is confused and does not "know" what is equal to zero. You should write: `((D[W[x, y], {x, 2}]) /. x -> 0) == 0`. The next problem is that the prim for the derivative is used for functions of a single variable. Otherwise, it is unclear with respect to which variable the derivative is calculated. I cannot guess, what is meant here: `w''''[x, y] - b^4 w[x, y] == f[x, y]`. I think you should make this clear.